# Camel doesn't stop after stopping the app on Server

Tags: spring, apache-camel, task, scheduled-tasks

I have a Spring scheduled task which uses Camel to do some business logic.I create an ear out of this application and is deployed on WAS. Now, for some reason , if i stop the app from WAS console, The camel threads kept running in the background. How can i attach my camel context with the Spring's context so that once spring context is destroyed, it destroy the Camel Context as well. sharing the code for understanding

```
DefaultCamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
context.addRoutes(route1);
context.addRoutes(route2);
context.start();
```

route1 and route2 are Camel routes which are defined as Spring beans as well.

this spawns 2 camel threads running in parallel. Now when I stop my app, these camel threds still keep running. How can i bind this camel context with Spring container so that once the container\context is destroyed all the underlying threads are also killed.

Answer (score 0):

Camel by default uses graceful shutdown. You can read more details in the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/graceful-shutdown.html)

Comment: I know about that and i do that when camel completes its job and the handles comes back to Spring's scheduled method. What i am asking is how to configure camel's shutdown if i am stopping my spring container?